# Passing data from custom renderer to custom control

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following `Xamarin.Forms` control in my project:

```
public partial class AutoCompleteView : Xamarin.Forms.View
{
    public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Text",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(string),
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty SuggestionsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Suggestions",
        returnType: typeof(IEnumerable<string>),
        declaringType: typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public IEnumerable<string> Suggestions
    {
        get => (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(SuggestionsProperty);
        set => SetValue(SuggestionsProperty, value);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public AutoCompleteView () : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

And the following custom Android renderer:

```
 public class AutoCompleteViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer<AutoCompleteView, AutoCompleteTextView>
{
    public AutoCompleteViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AutoCompleteView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            return;

        var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteTextView(this.Context);
        SetNativeControl(autoComplete);
        this.Control.SetSingleLine();


        this.Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (this.Element == null || this.Control == null)
            return;
        var autoComplete = (AutoCompleteView)sender;
        this.Control.Text = autoComplete.Text;
        if (autoComplete.Suggestions != null)
        {
            var suggestions = autoComplete.Suggestions.ToArray();
            this.Control.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Context, Resource.Layout.autoCompleteCell, suggestions);
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that control does not receive text from renderer (i.e. neither `Text` setter nor binded model's setter invoked). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you saying that `this.Control.Text = autoComplete.Text;` doesn't execute? If you put a breakpoint on that line and debug does the breakpoint get hit?

Comment: It does. It fires on element creating and when focus is lost. But after all, the binded property (`Text` I mean) does not update and remains empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank mjwills, I found a logic mistake here. `this.Control.Text = autoComplete.Text` should obviously be inverted (i.e. `autoComplete.Text = this.Control.Text`), since `this.Control` is a native control, which should pass text changes to custom `AutoCompleteView`.